# Inner of metric completion

Tags: analysis

I am reading a proof where we have the following:

- $M$ a metric space
- $N$ its metric completion

It is then stated: *for $y\in N$ let ($y_s$) be a Cauchy sequence converging to y with $y_s\in M$*.

I do not understand why can we choose $y_s\in M$.

Do we have *$y\in N\setminus M \Rightarrow y\in\partial M$* ?

**Edit**

It is my understanding a property of the completion is being the *smallest* complete space $N$ such that $M\subset N$, and so the intuition tells me the above should hold. But I did not manage proving it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $M$ is dense in $N$ by the very definition of completion.  Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space